# Yii 2 - Overriding files of mdm extension in vendor to extension folder using aliases in config

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app

I have installed **mdm extension** for admin in basic version of Yii2, that is located in vendor directory and I want to override some files into extension directory for UI changes, I referred this [link](https://recordnotfound.com/yii2-admin-mdmsoft-4894) and added some code in web and console file as:

```
'aliases' => [
        '@mdm/admin' => '@app/extensions/mdm/yii2-admin',
    ],
```

But no changes are reflected after doing this.

Comment: Did you installed this extension using composer?

Comment: Yes, using composer I've installed the mdm admin extension - `"mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "~2.0"`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely version installed by Composer conflicts with version which you unpacked manually. Instruction in documentation are for installing extension without using Composer, so they're definitely not considering the fact, that you have the same extension installed in two different places.

If you want to edit this extension you should uninstall composer version and copy whole extension into `extensions/mdm/yii2-admin`.

But probably better option would be to fork it, and add repository to your `composer.json` which will point to your fork:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/yourname/yii2-admin.git"
    }
],
```

And change dependency constraints to use `master` branch:

```
"require": {
    "mdmsoft/yii2-admin": "dev-master as 2.8.0",
    // ...
},
```

Then all necessary changes you're preforming in your fork (at `https://github.com/yourname/yii2-admin.git`) and fetching changes to main project using `composer update mdmsoft/yii2-admin`. It will simplify syncing changes from upstream - you just need to merge changes for upstream if you want to update your fork with lates changes from original extension repository.